What is the best way to visualize relationship between three variables?
I have a data like this:



Company
Providers
Paths




A
1
14


B
2
15


C
4
60


D
2
13



The greater the number of providers, the greater the paths. What might be the best way(graphical plots) to present this information?

How large is the dataset?  How many rows?  How many companies?  I gather company is a factor, but providers and paths are counts.  Is that correct?  What exactly to you want to show?

Arguably, your table is so simple that sorting it by the number of providers and/or paths, and presenting the resulting table could be as informative as a plot.
Otherwise, you could use a scatterplot with providers on the x-axis and paths on the y-axis, and plot the company name next to each point.
One might be tempted to use color to represent companies - but I think it would unnecessarily force the readers to go back and forth between the legend and the plot.
Also, note that if you had much more data with different companies for each row, then color wouldn't be very informative. I can think of two situations where colors might be a adequate option: if you had a lot of data but few companies; or if you wanted to highlight a specific company (you could use two contrasting colors to represent this company vs. the others).
